Optimize query with agregate function
I have this query, which durate 1.3s. Why is so long when I have all indexes? Can I somewhat optimize or simplify this query? I need to calculate data online. Saving to a table and regenerating once in a while is not something I want.
SELECT `countries`.*, `c2`.`country_name` AS `parent_name`,
       COUNT(countryperiods.countryPeriod_id) AS `numberCountryPeriods`,
       MIN(`from`) AS `min`, MAX(`to`) AS `max`,
       `continents`.`continent_id`, `continents`.`continent_name`,
       `continents`.`continent_seo`, `continents`.`continent_enabled` 
FROM `countries`
INNER JOIN `us`
LEFT JOIN `countries` AS `c2`
   ON c2.country_id = countries.parent_id
LEFT JOIN `s`
    ON countries.country_id = s.country_id
LEFT JOIN `countryperiods`
    ON countryperiods.country_id = countries.country_id
LEFT JOIN `continents`
    ON continents.continent_id = countries.continent_id
WHERE
    (countries.country_id = s.country_id) AND
    (f_user_id = '14') AND
    (s.id = us.f_s_id) AND
    (us_toChange = 1)
GROUP BY `countries`.`country_id`
ORDER BY `country_name` ASC
LIMIT 1

I am attaching an overview of tables and indexes.
countries
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `continent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_seo` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `countries`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`),
ADD KEY `continent_id` (`continent_id`),
ADD KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`);

s
CREATE TABLE `s` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `s`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD KEY `country_id` (`country_id`);

countryperiods
CREATE TABLE `countryperiods` (
  `countryPeriod_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryPeriod_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `countryperiods`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`countryPeriod_id`),
ADD KEY `country_id` (`country_id`);

continents
CREATE TABLE `continents` (
  `continent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `continent_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `continent_seo` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `continent_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `continents`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`continent_id`);

us
CREATE TABLE `us` (
  `uS_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `f_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_s_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `us_toChange` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `us`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uS_id`),
ADD KEY `f_s_id` (`f_s_id`),
ADD KEY `f_user_id` (`f_user_id`),
ADD KEY `us` (`f_user_id`,`f_s_id`) USING BTREE;

Explain


Problem: The f_user_id column which appears in the where clause has no alias.  It appears to belong to the userstamps table (listed last above), but that table is not part of the query.

Standard procedure here: Run EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ... to see what execution plan MySQL is using, and to find out which indices are being used.

The query is not correct. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY server SQL mode then fix the query. Also joining condition in INNER JOIN us is lost..

@TimBiegeleisen it was a typo in table name

@Akina I have it enable. What is not correct in query?

Incomplete grouping. You select non-aggregated columns which is not included into grouping expression which produces non-deterministic output. With mentioned server SQL mode set you'd receive Error 1055.

LEFT JOIN s ?? there isn't a published table called s

And could you please take the time to fix the syntax errors https://dbfiddle.uk/oQCBJQhM

Does WHERE     (countries.country_id = s.country_id)  make sense when you have LEFT JOIN s     ON countries.country_id = s.country_id ?

@P.Salmon I am sorry, I repair it. Thank you for tip. This one is already correct https://dbfiddle.uk/hC1flLON. Removing part of where will not change duration of query.

@Akina There was a typo. I tried in that setup from a colleague. Can you please take a look at it?

To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see the output of EXPLAIN as well as your table and index information. Please read this, then [edit] your question.

@O.Jones I added image with explain. Can you check it, please?

See if https://dbfiddle.uk/lkJ3IQZc is any better
